# Filter rows on dates depending on different column values

Tags: sql, teradata

I've been trying to filter rows with a certain value for `code` based on the values of task_dts.
Essentially I only want the rows **per id** where the `task_dts` timestamp falls between the `code_dts` timestamp of the current `code` and the `code_dts` of the **following** `code`.

For example; for the rows where `code` equals 'z', I only want the rows where the `task_dts` is in the range of the `code_dts` for value 'z' and value 'y'.
For the rows where the `code` equals 'y', I only want the rows where the `task_dts` is in the range of the `code_dts` for value 'y' and value 'x' etc

My table looks the following:

| rowid | id | code | code_dts | task | task_dts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | z | 2022-02-01 10:17:08.403000 | 1 | 2022-02-01 10:21:27.000000 |
| 2 | a | z | 2022-02-01 10:17:08.403000 | 2 | 2022-02-01 10:21:31.000000 |
| 3 | a | z | 2022-02-01 10:17:08.403000 | 3 | 2022-02-01 12:41:43.000000 |
| 4 | a | y | 2022-02-01 11:12:13.270000 | 1 | 2022-02-01 10:21:27.000000 |
| 5 | a | y | 2022-02-01 11:12:13.270000 | 3 | 2022-02-01 12:41:43.000000 |
| 6 | a | y | 2022-02-01 11:12:13.270000 | 8 | 2022-02-21 14:57:53.000000 |
| 7 | a | x | 2022-02-21 12:28:50.647000 | 6 | 2022-02-21 14:57:53.000000 |
| 8 | a | x | 2022-02-21 12:28:50.647000 | 7 | 2022-02-21 14:57:54.000000 |
| 9 | b | h | 2022-04-05 13:44:16.030000 | 1 | 2022-04-05 14:03:56.570000 |
| 10 | b | h | 2022-04-05 13:44:16.030000 | 2 | 2022-04-05 14:03:56.570000 |
| 11 | b | i | 2022-04-06 13:44:16.030000 | 1 | 2022-04-05 14:03:56.570000 |
| 12 | b | j | 2022-04-07 13:44:16.030000 | 3 | 2022-04-05 14:03:56.570000 |

The output would look like this:

| rowid | id | code | code_dts | task | task_dts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | z | 2022-02-01 10:17:08.403000 | 1 | 2022-02-01 10:21:27.000000 |
| 2 | a | z | 2022-02-01 10:17:08.403000 | 2 | 2022-02-01 10:21:31.000000 |
| 5 | a | y | 2022-02-01 11:12:13.270000 | 3 | 2022-02-01 12:41:43.000000 |
| 7 | a | x | 2022-02-21 12:28:50.647000 | 6 | 2022-02-21 14:57:53.000000 |
| 8 | a | x | 2022-02-21 12:28:50.647000 | 7 | 2022-02-21 14:57:54.000000 |
| 10 | b | h | 2022-04-05 13:44:16.030000 | 2 | 2022-04-05 14:03:56.570000 |
| 11 | b | i | 2022-04-06 13:44:16.030000 | 1 | 2022-04-05 14:03:56.570000 |
| 12 | b | j | 2022-04-07 13:44:16.030000 | 3 | 2022-04-05 14:03:56.570000 |

I've tried to solve this with qualify without succes. help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table expression to pre-compute the timestamp ranges. Then, filtering is easy.

For example:

```
select t.*
from t
join (
  select code, dt, lead(dt) over(order by dt) as next_dt
  from (select code, min(code_dts) as dt from t group by code) x
) y on t.code = y.code
where t.task_dts between y.dt and y.next_dt or y.next_dt is null
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading The Impaler's answer I finally understood your requirements :-)

This is the same logic based on Window Functions:

```
with cte as
 ( 
   select t.*
     -- next code_dts, i.e. at least one row will return 
     -- the code_dts of the following code 
     ,lead(code_dts,1,task_dts) over (order by code_dts) as next_dts
   from tab as t
 )
select *
from cte
qualify task_dts between code_dts
                     -- assign the next code's dts to all rows within the same code
                     and max(next_dts) over (partition by code)
;
```

Hard to tell which one will perfrom better...